# url and .css (javascript funtion) not defined in lightning renderer.js

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need to change the background-image of component(div) based on attribute.I have written a function in rendered.js and putting the image URL like below but getting an error that URL or .css is not defined.

```
({
afterRender: function(component, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();
    Var  imageURL;
   if (designattribute == 1){
      imageURL = '/something/something.....'
     }
    elseif (designattribute == 2){
     imageURL = '/something/something.....'
    } ...
    ....
   .... 
   else{
       imageURL =  ".......";
     } 

 component.find('divId').css('background-image',url(imageURL));

})
```

Image url is dynamic here and I need to set it to afterRender. I don't want to create multiple css classes and below approach doesn't work for me.

```
.This.backClass{
  'background-image': url({!imageURL})
}
```

Any help or approach appreciated.

Comment: Why use a background image? It would seem to me that using a simple `img` would be easier.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you completely but even for "img", I need to define "src" at run. I am facing issue to define the css attribute at run..I could make one CSS class for a image and then toggleClass at runtime but I was thinking of a way where  css attribute can be dynamically added..

Comment: You can set the src on an img dynamically, either via `component.find("someimage").src = ...` or by `<img src="{!v.imageUrl}" />`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simple syntax error : imageUrl is a variable, so declare it at the beginning of your code : var imageUrl ;

If .css doesn't work, try style.background-image='url('+ imageUrl+')' ;

If imageUrl can change during the life cycle of your component, I also suggest you encapsulate your code in a helper method and call it from afterRender and rerender methods

Comment: I did declare imageURl in the component. this is just sample code I written to explain.

Comment: "Xxxxx is not defined" is a typical syntax error message, check your code with http://jshint.com for example. Or post the full code here :)